# Android labelRes is 0

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am using `int stringID = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes` to get the application name resource ID. Then I use `context.getString(stringID)` to get the application name.
I get

```
 W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

Any idea why labelRes is 0?

Comment: post your java code when you call your twice methods

Comment: also post your android manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by specifying the label in `strings.xml` before the label was passed from the Gradle build file using `manifestPlaceholders`.

The problem in the third party library is they are not checking if `applicationInfo.lableRes` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

try this one it may help you

```
public static String getApplicationName(Context context) {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
    int stringId = applicationInfo.labelRes;
    return stringId == 0 ? applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString() : context.getString(stringId);
}


String appName=getApplicationName(context);
```

Comment: The problem is in the code of 3rd party library. I am trying to make sure that labelRes is not 0 or at least know why it is 0.